# Turn CapsLock On/OFF - During boot up of the forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help in writting a C# form application, where during the launch of the application based on entry in a configuration file. CAPSLOCK in the keyboard should be ON/OFF.

Answer (score 5):

Don't mess with the CapsLock key. Never ever - that is extremely bad UX.

Instead you should handle the KeyPress event on the respective textbox and convert the character to upper or lower case depending on your setting. Like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never say 'Never ever' :P I'm developing a uiAccess assistive program to help blind people mess with their CapsLock key using voice recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Based on further analysis and intensive research from various sources
Below is the code snippet which i coded to solve the problem i posted earlier

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enabling or Disabling CAPSLOCK button.
    /// Based on value retirevied from settings and also present CAPSLOCK button status.
    /// </summary>
    public void CharacterCasing()
    {
        if (settings.IsCapsLockOn ^ Console.CapsLock)
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
        }

    }
```

Your inputs and comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The reason i am doing this way is because there lot of  user controls in the form for which i had to handle key press which was not ideal and those were legacy user us controls, So i did not want to modify the existing code , thats the reason i had to write the code snippet mentioned above.

Comment: If the legacy user controls all derive from a common base usercontrol (like "MyExtendedTextBox") then you can simply put the code in the base control - this is a simple and low risk refactor. Even if they don't currently have that common base usercontrol it is simple to create and add.